# How to fix single-row subquery returns more than one row issue in select query in order to achieve the result in a desired manner?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Source Table

| Cost Category | Cost Category Type | Q1-2020 | Q2-2020 | Q3-2020 | Q4-2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee Impacted | Period Cost | 10 | 20 | 0 | 4000 |

Desired Result

| Cost Category | Cost Category Type | Quarter Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee Impacted | Period Cost | Q1-2020 | 10 |
| Employee Impacted | Period Cost | Q2-2020 | 20 |
| Employee Impacted | Period Cost | Q3-2020 | 0 |
| Employee Impacted | Period Cost | Q4-2020 | 4000 |

I am using trying to use the following query

```
SELECT 'Q'|| LEVEL ||'-2020' AS id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR((select ATTRIBUTE_34 || ',' || ATTRIBUTE_35 || ',' ||
                            ATTRIBUTE_36 || ',' || ATTRIBUTE_37
                       from view_form_539766),
                     '[^,]+',
                     1,
                     LEVEL) AS data
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR((select ATTRIBUTE_34 || ',' || ATTRIBUTE_35 || ',' ||
                                ATTRIBUTE_36 || ',' || ATTRIBUTE_37
                           from view_form_539766),
                         '[^,]+',
                         1,
                         LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `unpivot`, which was developed for such tasks:

> ```
> with a (
>   Cost_Category,
>   Cost_Category_Type,
>   Q1_2020,
>   Q2_2020,
>   Q3_2020,
>   Q4_2020
> ) as (
>   select
>     'Employee Impacted',
>     'Period Cost',
>     10,
>     20,
>     0,
>     4000
>   from dual
> )
> select *
> from a
> unpivot (
>   value
>   for Quarter_Year in (
>     q1_2020 as 'Q1-2020',
>     q2_2020 as 'Q2-2020',
>     q3_2020 as 'Q3-2020',
>     q4_2020 as 'Q4-2020'
>   )
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> COST_CATEGORY     | COST_CATEGORY_TYPE | QUARTER_YEAR | VALUE
> :---------------- | :----------------- | :----------- | ----:
> Employee Impacted | Period Cost        | Q1-2020      |    10
> Employee Impacted | Period Cost        | Q2-2020      |    20
> Employee Impacted | Period Cost        | Q3-2020      |     0
> Employee Impacted | Period Cost        | Q4-2020      |  4000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03b5ada6685c3b34f14279277bf946ae)*

Comment: Thanks, if you can please also suggest how to include transpose of a row only if lies between a specified start quarter and end quarter for example 'Q2-2019' should be included if it lies between two columns having the start quarter value and end quarter in the same format. I have converted it into date using add_months(to_date('0101'||substr('Q2-2013',4),'MM-DD-YYYY'),(substr('Q2-2013',2,1)-1)*3) in order to compare but not sure how to use it here, If you can please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as Union query:

```
Select CostCategory, CostCategoryType, 'Q1-2020' as QuarterYear, Q1-2020 as Value
from table1
union all
Select CostCategory, CostCategoryType, 'Q2-2020' as QuarterYear, Q2-2020 as Value
from table1
union all
.....
```

Comment: I have to fetch data from Q1-2013 till Q4-2025 using unions will unfortunately result in increase query cost